# Direct3D 9 functions return value

Tags: c++, directx, direct3d, directx-9, direct3d9

Since the function's return value is utilized for error message, how do the functions return the necessary information back to the caller?

For example:
[IDirect3D9::CreateDevice method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb174313%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: can you point to an example? (an msdn link would do)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if you take a look at that link you'll notice that it has some parameters marked `Out` this is important because this denotes what will be returned to the caller.

```
HRESULT CreateDevice(
[in]           UINT Adapter,
[in]           D3DDEVTYPE DeviceType,
[in]           HWND hFocusWindow,
[in]           DWORD BehaviorFlags,
[in, out]      D3DPRESENT_PARAMETERS *pPresentationParameters,
[out, retval]  IDirect3DDevice9 **ppReturnedDeviceInterface
);
```

In the above sample (copied and pasted from the MSDN link), you'll notice a parameter `ppReturnedDeviceInterface` is marked as being `**` or a pointer to a pointer, the caller would pass in a the address of their pointer and would be returned a pointer at that address. Also the `D3DPRESENT_PARAMETERS` structure passed in to `pPresentationParameters` will be updated on return, as noted by the `out` annotation.
Ex:

```
IDirect3DDevice9 *pDevice = NULL;

HRESULT hr = pD3D->CreateDevice(
                     D3DADAPTER_DEFAULT,
                     D3DDEVTYPE_HAL,
                     hwnd,
                     pPresentationParams,
                     &pDevice);
 if(SUCCEEDED(hr))
 {
    //pDevice should be non null at this point
 }
```

Comment: So, the caller is CreateDevice(
                     D3DADAPTER_DEFAULT,
                     D3DDEVTYPE_HAL,
                     hwnd,
                     pPresentationParams,
                     &pDevice);

while the value is return through D3DPRESENT_PARAMETERS *pPresentationParameters. Am I right?

Comment: There are actually two returned values, the `D3DPRESENT_PARAMETERS` is updated (as indicated by being marked `out`) and `pDevice` is assigned with a pointer to an `IDirect3DDevice9`. All of this is of course assuming that the return value of function is `S_OK` if not... all bets are off.

Comment: @zzz be ware of the terms return value and output parameters.

Comment: @zdd Correct, to make it more confusing Microsoft uses an annotation to declare a "Return Value" in the parameters that is the actual "Returned Value" without breaking the COM function signature requirements.